# Is there a way to have Google index a page but not cache it?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, google-index, google-cache, noarchive

I see that many popular sites have pages indexed in Google, but when I try to access Google's cache the page isn't there.

How can I go about doing the same thing with my site? I read that you have to make specific settings to the `robots.txt` file. What  do I need to add in that file?

If `robots.txt` isn't possible, is there another way to disable Google's cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a "Noarchive" Directive to prevent Google from caching specific web pages.

`<meta name="robots" content="noarchive">`

or for just Google:

`<meta name="googlebot" content="noarchive">`

There is **no** penalty for doing this.

[image]

Here are some typical scenarios to use Noarchive:

- Advertising you don’t want Google to cache.
- Any PPC landing pages you don’t want viewable to everybody.
- Internal documents you don’t want to be historically public.
- Any other sensitive documentation you don’t want a cache history of.

Comment: Any sensitive or internal documents probably should not be accessible to Google(bot) at all? Neither indexed nor archived.

Comment: @Bergi Correct, but not just Googlebot... _any_ bot? This question is not about noindex, robots.txt, or password protection.

Comment: Yes, I just don't understand why you listed it as "*some typical reasons to use Noarchive*" if those documents are already properly protected from public access

Comment: @Bergi revised to say "scenarios" rather than "reasons". From what information provided by OP can we to deduce that said things have been properly protected from public access already? I listed it because the annotation is frequently used when those things are desired.